# How to create multiple subtitles on a map annotation callout on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Currently I'm stuck on this problem of showing multiple lines of subtitles on a map annotation callout. I've found some tutorials that provides a custom callout, however, I'd prefer to use the default callout view, but with multiple subtitles (2 lines of subtitles, for example). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/

You can't do it with the default MKAnnotationView. This blog provides a work-around...