# Multiple Lines in Subtitle Area of Map Annotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotationview

I currently have an AnnotationDelegate prototyped like so:

```
@synthesize title; @synthesize subtitle; @synthesize coordinate;
```

However, when the subtitle is a string containing \n (newline characters), it doesn't continue on the next line.  Rather, it is just truncated and given a few trailing dots.  Is there some way to allow for multiple line subtitles?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no easy way.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942117/how-to-create-multiple-subtitles-on-a-map-annotation-callout-on-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345054/can-we-have-multiple-lines-in-subtitle-of-annotation-in-mapkit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342070/how-to-add-more-details-in-mkannotation-in-iphone-os, and many others for the options available.

Comment: there are a easy way @Anna plz check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831382/how-to-display-2-lines-of-text-for-subtitle-of-mkannotation-and-change-the-image